# CGRectMake for different iphone ipad orientations

Tags: iphone, ios4, orientation, cgrect

For following code I need to set different UIIMageView Positions according to iphone and ipad orientation.

```
// Animated images - centered on screen
animatedImages = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(
(SCREEN_WIDTH / 2) - (IMAGE_WIDTH / 2), 
(SCREEN_HEIGHT / 2) - (IMAGE_HEIGHT / 2) + STATUS_BAR_HEIGHT,
IMAGE_WIDTH, IMAGE_HEIGHT)];
```

As CGRect will be different for ipad portrait,iphone portrait, ipad landscape and iphone landscape.

How do I do this

```
if (Ipad Portrait orientation)
{ 
code with different position using CGRectMake (...............)
}
if (Iphone Portrait orientation)
{ 
code with different position using CGRectMake (...............)
}
if (Ipad Landscape orientation)
{ 
code with different position using CGRectMake (...............)
}
if (Iphone Landscape orientation)
{ 
code with different position using CGRectMake (...............)
}
```

Comment: Please format your post, and use the code tags, so it's easier to read.

Answer (score 3):

You can use the UIViewController's interfaceOrientation property.  It will give you one of the following values:

UIInterfaceOrientationPortrait,
UIInterfaceOrientationPortraitUpsideDown,
UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeLeft,
UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeRight

Your code would look like:

```
if (self.interfaceOrientation == UIInterfaceOrientationPortrait)
{
    ...
}
else if    // etc.
```

Answer (score 0):

You can differentiate between iPhone and iPad with

```
if (UI_USER_INTERFACE_IDIOM() == UIUserInterfaceIdiomPad)
{
     // The device is an iPad running iPhone 3.2 or later.
}
else
{
     // The device is an iPhone or iPod touch.
}
```

and you can differentiate between portrait and landscape with

```
if (UIInterfaceOrientationIsLandscape(self.interfaceOrientation))
{
     // The device is in landscape.
}
else
{
     // The device is in portrait.
}
```

Now combine this to get the customization as you like.